# Issues with the `sales_order_item_cancel` event in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: event-observer, magento2.4.1

I have made an API which cancel and order. This is part of the code:

```
// \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface
$this->orderManagement->cancel($order->getId());
```

The above code will called this method: `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item::cancel`,
where this event is dispatched:             `$this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_item_cancel', ['item' => $this]);`

The event is used by: `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\CancelOrderItemObserver::execute`
with the following code:

```
/**
 * Cancel order item
 *
 * @param   EventObserver $observer
 * @return  void
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $item */
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
    $children = $item->getChildrenItems();
    $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered() - max($item->getQtyShipped(), $item->getQtyInvoiced()) - $item->getQtyCanceled();
    if ($item->getId() && $item->getProductId() && empty($children) && $qty && $this->configuration->getCanBackInStock()) {
        $this->stockManagement->backItemQty($item->getProductId(), $qty, $item->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    }
    $this->priceIndexer->reindexRow($item->getProductId());
}
```

My problem is that the canceling the order takes too much time, on my local it takes almost 3 minutes. IF I comment the following lines:

```
 $this->stockManagement->backItemQty($item->getProductId(), $qty, $item->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
```

and

```
$this->priceIndexer->reindexRow($item->getProductId());
```

from the observer, the all canceling process it takes 3 seconds!. The fact is, if I cancel the order from the admin area, the results are the same! so the problem is not from my custom API!

Have anyone faced something like this? If YES, what can I do the reduce the execution time? 3 minutes(on my local and 1 min 30 seconds aprox. on live) is not acceptable!

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy guess based on the information you provided so far, but I suggest you install on your local machine a performance profiling tool like [blackfire.io](https://www.blackfire.io/) to pinpoint exactly where the time is consumed and it gets stuck, then engage into a more deep debugging session based on what you find in the results of the profiling.